# jQuery Load - Additional Parameter

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am using the **jQuery Load** method.

```
 $('#tabs-1').load("@Html.Raw(Url.Action("IndexTpUse",
                                    "Transactions"))", completed);

 function completed(response, status, xhr)
 {

 }
```

What I need is to send an additional parameter from the **load method** into the completed function. Is it possible?

So that my final result might be something like this:

```
 function completed(response, status, xhr, additionalParam)
 {

 }
```

Thanks

Comment: And where would that additional parameter come from, the serverside ?

Comment: just wrap completed method inside anonymous function, and pass parameters

Comment: @adeneo no. I need to send it from the client side .load method. This is a Javascript language doubt I guess.

Comment: @A.Wolff can you give me an example? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `bind` to predefine some function parameters:

```
$('#tabs-1').load("@Html.Raw(Url.Action("IndexTpUse","Transactions"))", completed.bind(null, 'my param value'));

 function completed(additionalParam, response, status, xhr)
 {

 }
```