# How to add additional parameters to jQuery validator function

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I am using [jQuery validate plugin](https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery-validate/1.19.1/jquery.validate.js) to validate the form data at the input point. For most of the pages, the validation is standards where I accept any non-empty value. However, there are forms in some pages which require specific validation (e.g. a pattern match)

I have included the generic validation function in the templates and the validation happens as expected. But I am finding it difficult to figure out how to `extend` the above functions only for specific pages by adding an additional lines of code, giving the main function the capability to perform page-specific validations. I have checked [1](https://stackoverflow.com/q/21026844/1609555), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/39354535/1609555) [3](https://stackoverflow.com/q/40602826/1609555) and many other answers and had no luck. I do not need to replace the entire validation function, but to add specific parameters based on page.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5007279/1609555) was not helpful since I am calling `onclick` function and NOT a simple function. What am I missing?

My main validation function is below

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    if(jQuery().validate) {
        jQuery('#maindataform').validate({
            ignore: ":hidden:not(select)",
            errorClass: "is-invalid",
            validClass: "is-valid",
            errorPlacement: function(error, element) {
                error.insertAfter(element);
            },
            //add rules parameters here
            //add message parameters here
        });

        jQuery('#maindataformbtn').click(function() {
            var formstatus = jQuery('#maindataform').valid();
            if (formstatus) {
                //alert ("valid");
                jQuery('#maindataform').submit();
            }
        });
    }
});
```

Page-specific parameters I am trying to add

```
    rules: {
        nic: {
            pattern: "^[0-9]{9}(V|X)$)|(^[0-9]{12}$"
        },
    },
    messages: {
        nic: {
            pattern: "NIC can have 9 numbers with 'V' or 12 numbers only"
        },
    }
```

Comment: See item 1b in this answer:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/9056425/594235

Comment: You could also use the `.rules()` method to dynamically add the rules on the specific page.

Comment: @Sparky Thank you. `.rules()` in *2b* worked well even though 1b did not. Is there any method to display messages such as `.messages()`? (I tried messages() but didn't work)

Comment: `messages` is a parameter you can use inside of the `.rules()` option.  Please refer to the documentation.   http://jqueryvalidation.org/rules

Comment: @Sparky Oh sorry I missed that. Thank you!